# ListView item deletion not happening

Tags: android, listview, android-intent, android-activity

The aim is that store the string in the  normal listview and then user touch(click) it move to next page along with user selected item. Once user click "Reject button" in the Operation.java, the should go-off from the List.java activity. It is not happening. It shows "Unfortunately, System has stopped".

MainActivity.java

```
   public static int loop_exute=0  // first page variable
   Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), List.class);  
   startActivity(i);
```

List.java

```
import android.R.string;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

public class List extends ActionBarActivity implements OnItemClickListener {

      private ListView mainListView ;
      private ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter ;
      Button buttonSum;  
      static String[]  name; 
      ArrayList<String> planetList = new ArrayList<String>();
      int pos;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);
         mainListView = (ListView) findViewById( R.id.mainListView );

         Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

      if(MainActivity.loop_exute==0) // acces 1st page value because the string array value sholuld load only once in its life time
         {

            MainActivity.loop_exute=MainActivity.loop_exute+2;

            name = new String[] { "AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "DDD"
                  }; 

            planetList.addAll( Arrays.asList(name) );

            listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.simplerow, planetList);

            mainListView.setAdapter( listAdapter );  

            //mainListView.getChildAt(0).setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

            show();

}
else  // second time call 
{
              Intent intent = getIntent();        
            if(intent.hasExtra("MESSAGE"))
              {
                    Bundle  bd = getIntent().getExtras();
                    if(!bd.getString("MESSAGE").equals(null))
                     {
                        String object=bd.getString("MESSAGE");
                        int pos=planetList.indexOf(object);
                    planetList.remove(pos);
                    listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();             //show();
                      }

             }
    }
}


public void show()
{ 
mainListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){ 
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) 

        {


            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Operation.class);  

            i.putExtra("Value2",name[pos]);  
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.list, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Operation.java

```
reject = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
reject.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

         Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), List.class);  
        i.putExtra("MESSAGE",value1); //send the list item value what we    select in previous activity

           startActivity(i);


    }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

In the setOnClickListener under Operation.java, you are trying to start another activity. Instead, insert code to manually destroy the activity. You can also use the finish() method. Here's a link to know more about it:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle

Comment: Ok. Sure . I will try. Thanks for the reply yaar.  Sorry I can't vote because less Reputation I am having